# Check if db contains one or more of 1000 IDs on Google App Engine running Python

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I have a app that has Facebook-integration. I am getting a list of a users facebook friends (IDs) and want to query my back end to find out which users have signed up for my service

players are inserted when signing up using their unique FBID

```
player = Player.get_or_insert(FBID)
```

If my backend receives a array of thousands of FBIDs, whats the most optimal way to query the db to find which of these IDs exist in the database?

I can run through the array and select from players where ID=FBID,

```
for FBID in FBIDs:
    player = Player.get_by_id(FBID)
    if player is not None:
         responseArray.append(player)
```

but this will result in N queries, which is not very optimal, considering there will proably be thousands of players doing this kind if request to the database.

Is it more cost-effective to do a query like `"select from Players where ID == FBID#1 or ID == FBID#2 or FBID#3 ..."`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the FBID as the entity key id, you would be able to get_multi() with a list of keys.  By knowing how to construct the Key, this may be more efficient.

Assigning the Key id:
[Google App Engine NDB custom key id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058327/google-app-engine-ndb-custom-key-id)

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions
ndb.get_multi(keys, **ctx_options)
Fetches entities identified by the passed sequence of keys.
Returns a list. Each list item is either a Model instance or None if the key wasn't found.

You can evaluate different approaches with appstats:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: Sequence of keys, thats an array of FBIDs? like ["2149132","23482384238","83482384",...] ?

Comment: Not quite.  I assumed there would be something like a User entity on the appengine side.  When create that, you can set the id to the FBID.  Then when checking for it's existence, create a User key with that known id or ids.  This list of User keys is passed to get_multi. The referenced SO url shows how to set the entity id.

Comment: Yes. Worked when i constructed keys using ndb.Key('Player', FBID)