# How to set users.userid as a key in ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to write appengine python code that uses the built-in authentication 'users' object and using userid as an ndb key

Here's my model:

```
 class UserAccounts(ndb.Model):
     UserID = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)
```

In my handler:
I get the current user

```
user = users.get_current_user()
```

Instantiate an entry

```
account = Models.UserAccounts()
```

Set the userid to the ndb entry

```
account.UserID = userid
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
Expected Key, got '113804764227149124198'
```

Where am I going wrong?  As much as possible, I'd like to use a `KeyProperty` instead of `StringProperty` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this UserAccounts(id=user_id), this way the user_id is the key. With this approach you can remove the userid field from the model definition

Comment: I've been doing research, the answer I found is similar to: this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058327/google-app-engine-ndb-custom-key-id     I was confusing Keys to IDs.  In the RDBMS world, an ID is a tuple and thought I have to include it in the model.  So the solution is, I will use StringProperty for the UserID field.  But upon creation of an object, I will include the ID='' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

by:

```
account.UserID = userid
```

I assume you meant:

```
account.UserID = user.user_id()
```

The user id is a *string*, not a *key*, so you can't use a `KeyProperty` here.  In fact, AFAIK, [`User`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects) objects as returned from `users.get_current_user()` don't have a key (at least not one that is documented) since they aren't datastore entries.  There is an [`ndb.UserProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties), but I don't think it's use is generally encouraged.

What performance reasons are you referring to?

Comment: Your assumption of account.UserID = user.user_id() is correct.  What I'm trying to solve is that in here [link]https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries there is talk about "If you are sure that there was just one Account with that userid, you might prefer to use userid as a key. Account.get_by_id(...) is faster than Account.query(...).get()."  By saying use userid as a key, I assumed it mean to set it as a KeyProperty.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Gerard -- No, don't make it a KeyProperty.  It means that you set it as the ID when you create an instance:  `account = UserAccount(id=user_id)` and then `account = UserAccount.get_by_id(user_id)`