# Google App Engine: defining custom id and querying

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to define a custom string as an ID so I created the following Model:

```
class WikiPage(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    history = ndb.DateTimeProperty(repeated=True)
```

Based on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058327/google-app-engine-ndb-custom-key-id), I believe this is right.

Now I try to query by this id by:

```
entity = WikiPage.get_by_id(page) # page is an existing string id, passed in as an arg
```

This is based on the [NDB API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id).

This however isn't returning anything -- entity is None.
It only works when I run the following query instead:

```
entity = WikiPage.query(WikiPage.id == page).get()
```

Am I defining my custom key incorrectly or misusing get_by_id() somehow?

Comment: Hmm, looking at the Datastore, it looks like I haven't defined the id/key correctly. The unique constraint isn't being enforced.

Comment: You have used the id field as a stringproperty. Rename it and also use this new field it for the id of your model.

Comment: @voscausa Sorry, but could you elaborate a little further?

Comment: id is special and part of the ndb.Key, See example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
class WikiPage(ndb.Model):
    your_id = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    history = ndb.DateTimeProperty(repeated=True)

entity = WikiPage(id='hello', your_id='hello', content=...., history=.....)
entity.put()

entity = WikiPage.get_by_id('hello')
```

or

```
key = ndb.Key('WikiPage','hello')
entity = key.get()
entity = WikiPage.get_by_id(key.id())
```

and this still works:

```
entity = WikiPage.query(WikiPage.your_id == 'hello').get()
```